# When can a described Pending Intent could exist?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

While setting PendingIntent on a button click and choosing the Flag, Now I feel like not understanding the concept of existence of Pending Intent with the same description.

refer the documentation :

```
    /**
 * Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
 * the current one should be canceled before generating a new one.
 * For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
 * {@link #getService}. <p>You can use
 * this to retrieve a new PendingIntent when you are only changing the
 * extra data in the Intent; by canceling the previous pending intent,
 * this ensures that only entities given the new data will be able to
 * launch it.  If this assurance is not an issue, consider
 * {@link #FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT}.
 */
public static final int FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT = 1<<28;
```

In My Case, I have to set on click pendingIntent for 2 views on a remote view ( used in App Widget ), and the pending intent is same in the sense, I want to start the same activity on click of both of the views.

Lets say, What if I create as instance of PendingIntent with FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag and set the same pendingIntent on onClick of these two views?
Or By using different request Codes we can get 2 unique Pending Intent doing the same thing.

Comment: When you create a `PendingIntent` and provide `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, then any matching `PendingIntent` that **already exists** will be canceled. The new `PendingIntent` which you get from the call to create this one is valid. What exactly is your question? What is unclear?

Comment: so is it possible to set this pendint intent to multiple views onClick

Comment: Yes, you can use the same `PendingIntent` on multiple `View`s, as long as you don't need to know which `View` was clicked. Otherwise, you'll need different (unique) `PendingIntent`s with different "extras" so that you can tell which `View` was clicked. Is that your problem? I'm trying to figure out how to formulate an answer to your question.

Comment: Hi @DavidWasser, thanks for helping me.
by this line 'Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
 * the current one should be canceled before generating a new one.' - 
Suppose there are some view which has linked pending intent on click, Now if use create another pending intent with flag_cancel_current, the previous view onclick wouldn't work?

Comment: and what does FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE mean, earlier i though, i should add and operator with the flags to utilize both of them properties.

Comment: @ David Wasser  I totally understand, its not very clear what is my wy uestion?
I think, Now I just want to understand all the possible use cases about pending intent with examples.